# Compute $\sum_{l=1}^\infty N(l)z^l$ (find a simple expression for this sum)

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Consider the doubling map $T =T_2 :\Bbb T→\Bbb T$ (where $\Bbb T = [0, 1]$ with $0$ and $1$ identified) defined as$T(θ)=2θ$ (mod $1$). What is the number $N(l)$ of points $\theta ∈\Bbb T$ are there such that $T^l(θ) = θ$, for fixed $l ≥ 1$. Compute  $\sum_{l=1}^\infty N(l)z^l$ (find a simple expression for this sum).

Here for fixed $l ≥ 1$ we have $\frac{p}{2^l-1}$ is fixed where $p=0,\ldots,2^l-2$ so, $N(l)=2^l-1$ and $\sum_{l=1}^\infty N(l)z^l=\sum_{l=1}^\infty (2z)^l-\sum_{l=1}^\infty z^l$. Now how to simply it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$
\sum_{l=1}^\infty w^l=\frac w{1-w}\quad \text{for} \ |w|<1,
$$
we get
$$
\sum_{l=1}^\infty N(l)z^l=\frac {2z}{1-2z}-\frac z{1-z}=\frac{z}{(1-2z)(1-z)}
$$
for $|z|<1/2$.

> Now that you are at it, you can try to compute the corresponding zeta function
>   $$
> \zeta_T(z)=\exp\sum_{l=1}^\infty \frac{N(l)}l z^l.
> $$
>   Hint: note that $\zeta_T'(z)=\zeta_T(z)\sum_{l=1}^\infty N(l)z^{l-1}$.

Comment: I did not get your last part about zeta function. Are you trying to say that the answer would be $\frac{z \zeta_T'(z)}{\zeta_T(z)}$?

Comment: Actually, I am a beginner at Ergodic theory. Maybe what you have written in the coloured region will come later. I didn't understand that part.

Comment: I see. One often does not look at $\sum_{l=1}^\infty N(l)z^l$, but instead at $\zeta_T(z)$, precisely in the context of ergodic theory (still, as you noted, the two are related). It turns out that the asymptotic behavior the the zeta function gives information about the dynamics in some nontrivial ways (although as always more periodic points tend to means more complicated behavior), also of Tauberian type. The theory is extremely rich for hyperbolic systems (and the associated symbolic dynamics).